# PHP передать данные из модели в представление

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, недавно начал изучать PHP, практикуюсь на разработке интернет магазина.
Столкнулся с такой задачей. Необходимо в шаблон header.php отобразить имя текущего пользователя и фото.

К примеру как я это делаю для личного кабинета:

**Контроллер личного кабинета**

```
//получаем идентификатор юзера из сессии
$userId = User::checkLogged();
//получаем информацию о пользователе из БД
$user = User::getUserById($userId);

require_once(ROOT . '/views/cabinet/index.php');
return true;
```

**Функция в модели User**

```
  $db= Db::getConnection();
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id';
  $result = $db->prepare($sql);
  $result->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  //получить данные в виде массива
  $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $result->execute();

  return $result->fetch();
```

**Вывод в представление личного кабинета**

```html
<?php include './views/layouts/header.php' ?>
<section class="main_content">
  <?php echo $user['name']; ?>
</section>
<?php include './views/layouts/footer.php' ?>
```

---

Не понимаю как можно вывести имя пользователя в header.php
Пробовал так:`<?php echo User::getUserById($user['name']); ?>`
Но это работает если только перейти в личный кабинет, тогда имя отображается в шапке, если перейти на другую страницу исчезает.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Какой то фреймворк используете, судя по всему?

Comment: Нет, MVC развернут в ручную, только начал учиться, рановато мне фреймворки трогать

Comment: как как, в сессию после авторизации записать сведения. оттуда выводить в хэдер. зы: лучше бы изучили какой-либо распространенный MVC-фреймворк, а не свое городили. Ну или начните по крайней мере с использования html-шаблонизаторов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи вы можете использовать `SESSION`, т.е в модели `User` после авторизации, полученные данные `$user` сохраните в `session`, простой например:
`$_SESSION['user'] = $user;`, а дальше уже сможете получать данные пользователя во всех страницах, `$_SESSION['user']['name'];`.
Это примитивный пример, просто для того чтобы понятна была логика, вам желательно будет почитать документацию [Session](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php)

После  того как пользователь выйдет из системы, вам надо удалить данную сессию...

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно